# Uso del verbo "tenere" riferito a sentimenti che occupano l'animo di una persona

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Ho certi dubbi in merito all'accezione numero 37 del verbo "tenere" sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000882.jpg):

> Pervadere intensamente, impressionare in forza
> una  persona,  occupandone  l'animo  in  modo  esclusivo (un  sentimento,  in  partic.  l'amore,  anche  personificato, un  desiderio,  uno  stato  d'animo);  assillare,  tormentare senza  tregua  (un  dolore,  una  pena);  suscitare  uno  stato
> di  malessere  spirituale,  di  turbamento,  di  affanno;  in­quietare,  angosciare  (un  dubbio,  una  preoccupazione, un timore).

Ho due domande al riguardo. La prima: questa accezione è ancora in uso nel linguaggio comune? Gli esempi Novecenteschi del GDLI sono di poeti.

La seconda: non sono sicura di aver capito come si usa questo verbo con questo significato. Potreste fare qualche esempio? Potrei dire la frase seguente?

> La nostalgia sempre mi tiene.

Comment: La storia del perché sono arrivata a interessarmi da questa particolare accezione del verbo "tenere" è un po' lunga da spiegare. Se lo credete necessario, però, posso cercare di farlo.

Comment: Non saprei dare una risposta esauriente, ma direi che si può considerare equivalente a *dominare*, *possedere*: la nostalgia mi domina, mi possiede. La frase va bene, però anche a me sembra abbastanza letterario,  quantomeno poco quotidiano, anche se mi sembra si possa usare: *la paura mi tiene*, *il desiderio  mi tiene*.  Per un esempio famoso dell'accezione *dominare* c'è Pascoli: "Romagna solatia, dolce paese,
cui regnarono Guidi e Malatesta;
cui tenne pure il Passator Cortese,
re della strada, re della foresta": *cui tenne* vuol dire *che dominò*.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Bel esempio! La prima parte fa pensare tanto a Dante... Ma direi che il tuo commento vada bene come risposta.

Comment: Grazie Charo. Se pensi che va bene allora lo posto come risposta.

Comment: Mi sembra un uso principalmente letterario. Per un uso comune e un significato simile mi viene  in mente l’uso  in frasi tipo: - *la paura/l’angoscia  mi tiene sveglio la notte.*  - *tenere qualcuno col fiato sospeso* .

Comment: “La nostalgia sempre mi tiene (col cuore in pena)” diresti oggi.

Comment: @Hachi: Dalla risposta di BakerStreet mi sembra di capire che "La nostalgia mi domina sempre" sarebbe ancora più naturale nel linguaggio comune, no? O forse ancora meglio qualche costrutto nella forma passiva... qualcosa come "Sono sempre dominato dalla nostalgia" oppure "Il mio animo è sempre pervaso dalla nostalgia".

Comment: Personalmente direi: *”mi prende sempre la nostalgia.*”la frase “*Il mio animo è sempre pervaso dalla nostalgia*” è corretta ma non colloquiale.

Answer (score 1):

*Tenere*, riferito a sentimenti,  si può considerare equivalente a *dominare*, *possedere*: *la nostalgia mi domina, mi possiede*.

La frase *la nostalgia sempre mi tiene* quindi va bene, però anche a me suona abbastanza letteraria (anche per l'inversione di *sempre* e *mi tiene*, *mi tiene sempre* sarebbe più prosaico).

Quantomeno suona poco quotidiano, anche se mi sembra si possa usare: *la paura mi tiene, il desiderio mi tiene.*

Per un esempio famoso dell'accezione *dominare* c'è Pascoli:

*Romagna solatìa, dolce paese,*

*cui regnarono Guidi e Malatesta;*

*cui tenne pure il Passator Cortese,*

r*e della strada, re della foresta.*

(*cui tenne* qui vuol dire *che dominò*.)